# convert pandas dataframe to list of tuples and drop all pandas datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need to convert a dataframe into a format that can be inserted into a sql table.

```
data_tuples = [tuple(row) for row in df.values]
```

How do I remove all the non python datatypes from a pandas dataframe (including np ints and nans and NaTs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to do it efficiently, use corresponding pandas method - [to_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# conn = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname')
conn = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname')
df.to_sql('table_name', conn)
```

where `conn` is a SQLAlchemy engine connection object

[Docs: using SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#postgresql)

Comment: I am not able to use a conn object in my case

Comment: @user113531, how are you going to write to the DB (please specify which kind of  DB you are using) from Python?

Comment: I only have a psycopg2 conn object, and it doesnt seem to work with the pandas function.